# Made a mistake when Jumpstarting the Car

Tags: batteries, ground, automotive

I made a mistake in connecting the cables for jump start.

Instead of attaching one of the negative cables to the negative pole of the donor battery and attaching the other negative cable to a metal piece of the car with dead battery to create a ground, I reversed the negative cables by mistake. In other words, connected negative cable to negative pole of car with dead battery and the other negative cable to metal piece of donor battery.
Although it took a while to jump start the car with dead battery, it eventually started with the wrong connection.

Could this mistake have possibly caused any damage?

Comment: the only reason that you connect to a metal frame in the dead car is so you do not create sparks near the dead battery when connecting the ground ... the battery could be emitting hydrogen gas ... connection to the car frame should always be the last connection to be attached and the first connection to be removed

Comment: BTW, that is not really `reversing the cable`

Comment: What's the make and model of your car? Some newer ones come with backfeed protection, which might have saved you from some serious damage. Also, was the car completely off when you did this?

Comment: make and model of car is 2012 honda crv.

Comment: car was completely off when I did this.

Comment: As long as you didn't connect the negative terminal (or car body) of one battery to the positive terminal of the other, there should be no problem.

Comment: If the cars are working now I wouldn't worry about it. Also fyi this isn't on-topic for the EE stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

The reccomended connection of the negative cable to the engine block or transmission makes a short path from the donor battery to the starter motor of the sick car. And also reduces the risk of a hydrogen gas explosion.

Your alternative scheme resulted in a longer path from the donor battery to the starter, which probably resulted in more difficult starting. it's unlikely to have caused any damage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyqK3F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>